# How to retrieve label text in pinescript and be able to paste that somewhere?

Tags: pine-script

I'm unable to retrieve the label text, looking to be able to copy it on the clipboard to be able to paste it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to copy the text from on-chart labels/tables at the moment, unfortunately.